# Multiple file upload Html Jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to upload two files,
but the submit button in the webpage is not working. it won't trigger the  event. 
but still not working.However its works when I upload a single file. Here J-query is used for change on select drop-down list . if its MMS or VCF then we have to upload second file. at time only submit is not working.

```
        $("select#msgtype").change(function () {

            var mt =   $("#msgtype").val();



            if(mt == 'VCF' || mt == 'MMS'){
            $("#taM").hide();
            $("#bus11").show();
            }else{
            $("#taM").show();
            $("#bus11").hide();
            }
            });


    });


function fun()
{
    alert("submit");
       window.document.form11.action="newcamp.jsp";
       window.document.form11.method= "post";
        window.document.form11.enctype="multipart/form-data";
       window.document.form11.submit();
}
```

and html form

```
 <form name="form11" >

<table>
    <tr>
      <td><label class="lab">MSISDN:</label></td>
        <td><label class="lab1"><%= msisdn %></label></td>

   </tr>
         <tr>
      <td><label class="lab">SourceAddress:</label></td>
        <td><input type="Text" id="c" size="35" class="text1" name="c" /></td>

</tr>


<tr>
      <td><label class="lab">CampaignName:</label></td>
    <td><input type="Text" id="c1" size="35" class="texta" name="cname"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td><label class="lab">Message Type:</label></td>
    <td> <select name="cp" class="texta" id="msgtype"  style="width: 328px " >
                        <option value="TEXT">Text</option>
                        <option value="FLASH">Flash Message</option>
                        <option value="VCF">Business Card</option>
                        <option value="unicode">Language/Unicode Message</option>
                        <option value="MMS">MMS</option>
                        </select></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label class="lab">Message:</label></td>
  <td><div id="bus11">
      <input type="file"  name="file"  />
 </div>
  <div id ="taM">
<textarea rows=3 cols=35 name="msg" id="msg1" class="texta"></textarea>

</div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label class="lab">StartTime:</label></td>
  <td>
    <input type="Text" id="demo1" size="35" name="stime" class="texta" on/>
    <img src="images/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true)" style="cursor:pointer"/>

</td>
</tr>
<td><label class="lab">EndTime:</label></td>
  <td>
    <input type="Text" id="demo2" size="35" class="texta" name="etime" />
    <img src="images/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo2','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true)" style="cursor:pointer"/>

</td>

<tr>
  <TD> </TD>
  <TD></TD>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label class="lab">ListofMSISDN:</label></td>
  <td>
        <input type="file" id="fl1" name="file"  />
  </td>

<tr>
  <td COLSPAN=2><CENTER><br>
              <input TYPE="submit" id="submit1" NAME="submit" VALUE="submit" onclick="fun();" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input TYPE="reset" class="button" /></CENTER></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

thanks for your quick reply but when i try to upload two file at that time its not even going to jsp file  ......... my jsp code is

```
List<String> field = new ArrayList<String>();
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);


for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                field.add(fieldvalue);
            } else {


                 InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                 myString = IOUtils.toString(filecontent, "UTF-8");

            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple files in jsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431294/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-jsp)